# In React Native using "react-native-wifi-p2p" this library,so startDiscoveringPeers method is working in debug mode but not working in release apk

Tags: javascript, react-native, wifi-direct, wifip2p

In React Native using "react-native-wifi-p2p" this library ,I am trying to connect two android devices for sending data from one device to other device using this library but in debug mode it is working to search Nearby Devices but when i create a release build or apk ,then it is not able to search any nearby devices.

I tried almost all solutions like check permissions in AndroidManifest.xml and check in logcat in android studio.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.